# Icon in input field overlaps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using a input field with type="text". I added icons on both the sides of text box to increment and decrement the numbers inside the textbox. It works fine till I increase the size of icon. Because, icon is big enough that it is overlapping the given input.

```
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Rank</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="number">
    <button mat-button matPrefix mat-icon-button>
       <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px">add_box</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
       <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px">indeterminate_check_box</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I customize input field so that it won't overlap the given input?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use flex-box like this.

```
<mat-form-field >
    <mat-label>Rank</mat-label>
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <button mat-button matPrefix mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px">add_box</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="number">
        <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon style="font-size: 40px">indeterminate_check_box</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Icons are displaying in a stack. I wanted them on sides of textbox.

Comment: Both icons are in stack or your textbox is also displaying in stack with those icons

Comment: Icons inside textbox  are stacked up.

Comment: No, It should be on each side. I think we need to customise input field so that it moves in between the icons.

Comment: like this icon-textBox-icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217468/discussion-between-maruthi-eranki-and-ankit).